# In the Google Calendar API, how do I determine if a calendar is google-created calendar, or a user-created worskpace calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I need a way to distinguish a google-created calendar (ex. "Holidays in United States") from a user-created calendar (ex. "Engineering Department") in the Google Calendar API. There doesn't seem to be a distinct field for this, so I've been trying to find a pattern in the calendar's fields. From the CalendarList API:

```
{
  ...
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
      "etag": "\"1616104281883000\"",
      "id": "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
      "summary": "Holidays in United States",
      "description": "Holidays and Observances in United States",
      ...
    },
    {
      "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
      "etag": "\"1623344030696000\"",
      "id": "c_g3s8ze0hkg2mc6kabr33f6r0ro@group.calendar.google.com",
      "summary": "Engineering Department",
     ...
    }
  ]
```

It seems like the only differentiating pattern is in the structure of the `id` field. The Google-created calendars have a readable email username, and the email domain is `group.v.calendar.google.com`. The user-created calendar on the other hand has a seemingly random string of characters as the username, and the email domain is `group.calendar.google.com` (notice the **.v** is missing).

This is a single example, but from the other examples I've seen the pattern is consistent. I haven't been able to find this pattern explicitly stated anywhere in the Google Calendar API docs, but maybe I'm missing something. Is this pattern explicitly stated anywhere? Or am I going about this wrong, and should be using a different feature of the API to distinguish these cases?

Comment: I dont think there is one

Comment: I tried to view the ids of my calendars and it seems that your theory proves that the difference of `.v` is true. If it stays true to your use case, feel free to use that difference to identify if it's google created or not. Also checked for the documentations and articles but doesn't seem to find anything.